# PDF of uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Find the uniform distribution of the continuous type that has he same mean and the same variance as those pf a chi--square distribution with 8 degrees of freedom. My solution: for the mean- $\frac {a+b}2=\alpha\beta=4x2=8$ How about for the variance? I understand that it is equal to $\alpha \beta^2=16$

Answer (score 1):

The expected value and variance of a random variable $X$ that is uniformly distributed on the interval $[a,b]$ are given by $$\begin{align*} \operatorname{E}[X] &= \frac{a+b}{2}, \\ \operatorname{Var}[X] &= \frac{(a-b)^2}{12}, \end{align*}$$ respectively.  Since the first is equal to $8$, and the second is equal to $16$ for a chi-squared distribution with $8$ degrees of freedom, solve the resulting system for $a, b$.